# how can i get place marker in google map api v3?

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i was using google map apis v2 in my project. Now i want to change google map api version to v3. In the old code i was parsing the json string in the following way

```
 JSONObject placemark =  json.getJSONArray("Placemark").getJSONObject(0);       
                    AddressDetail address = new AddressDetail();
                    address.setFullAddress(placemark.getString("address"));
                    JSONObject area = placemark.getJSONObject("AddressDetails").getJSONObject("Country").getJSONObject("AdministrativeArea");
                    address.setCounty(area.getString("AdministrativeAreaName"));
                    JSONObject subArea = area.getJSONObject("SubAdministrativeArea"); 
                    address.setTown(subArea.getString("SubAdministrativeAreaName"));
                    JSONObject locality = subArea.getJSONObject("Locality");
                    address.setLocalityName(locality.getString("LocalityName"));
                    address.setPostCode(locality.getJSONObject("PostalCode").getString("PostalCodeNumber"));
                    address.setStreet(locality.getJSONObject("Thoroughfare").getString("ThoroughfareName"));
```

but when i change Google map version to v3 and generate url to

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&latlng=51.520205,-0.1379954

and send request to server.Getting json having no placemark in it.

how can i get placemark in google map api v3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of the response changed in V3 of the geocoding web service.  You'll need to modify your code to remap to the new structure.  Though it's not that hard.

For example, `FullAddress` in your code is based on `formatted_address` and `Street` = `route`.  And so on.  You can see the full list of elements here:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the code in the [Google Maps API v3 Geocoder Tool](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v3-geocoder-tool.html), it probably has what you need.

One thing though: generating requests directly to the API at http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json is **not** the right thing to do in JavaScript. It happens to work because the API is in the same domain, but you should never do that. Instead, you should always use the [Geocoding Service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding.html) that is part of the Maps JavaScript V3 API.

Using this service you don't actually need to parse the JSON response at all, the API will do it for you and then you'll have an array of [Geocoding Results](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding.html#GeocodingResults). There, `results[0]` would replace `json.getJSONArray("Placemark").getJSONObject(0);`

To see how you'd translate your whole address extraction code, look at the source code for the above geocoder tool. Instead of an object tree, V3 gives you a flat array (`address_component`). Each component has a `short_name`, a `long_name` and an array (`types`) of [Address Component Types](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding.html#GeocodingAddressTypes). These types are what tells you how the components relate to each other.

Also, you should never assume that there will always be a component of any given type. Your current code relies blindly on the presence of a `locality` in the response, but that will not always be the case.